# Taking screenshots with the command line of a specific window

Tags: command-line, screen-capture

I wanna take a screenshot of a specific application using the command line. Doing

> screencapture -h

Shows option "-o"

> -o  in window capture mode, do not capture the shadow of the window

Which sounds like it might do what I need, but I am lost on how to actually use this option. Google did not turn up any answers

Thanks!

Comment: I think you’d need window ID

Comment: How do I get that? Seems kinda tough to get: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/56561/how-do-i-find-the-windowid-to-pass-to-screencapture-l

Comment: Duplicate of https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/378122/237687

Comment: @Solar Mike, IMO This question is not a duplicate of the linked question in your comment as that one is dealing with "specific regions" and specifically the use of the `-R<x,y,w,h> capture screen rect` _option_ **not** a "specific window" as in the title of this question, which will require the use of either the `-i` or `-l<windowid>` _options_ depending on specifically how it is to be captured. I guess one could say it's somewhat related, but it's not a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To capture a window using `screencapture` in **Terminal**, you have two *options*:

**Interactively**

```
-i         capture screen interactively, by selection or window
               control key - causes screen shot to go to clipboard
               space key   - toggle between mouse selection and
                             window selection modes
               escape key  - cancels interactive screen shot
```

You can use the `-o` *option* in conjunction with the `-i` *option* to not capture the shadow of the window, e.g.: `-oi`

**Programmatically**

```
-l<windowid> capture this windowsid
```

The `-i` *option* appears to be self-explanatory while the `-l<windowid>` *option* gives no additional info as with the `-i` *option*.

---

The `<windowid>`, for some windows can be ascertained by using **AppleScript** in the following example:

```
screencapture -l$(osascript -e 'tell app "Safari" to id of window 1') test.png
```

You can use the `-o` *option* in conjunction with the `-l` *option* to not capture the shadow of the window, e.g.: `-ol`

Some applications will not work with this method, however here are some alternatives:

- [screenshot: Better macOS screenshots via the Terminal](https://github.com/thismachinechills/screenshot)
- [GetWindowID](https://github.com/smokris/GetWindowID)

<sub>Reference: [How do I find the windowid to pass to screencapture -l?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/56561/how-do-i-find-the-windowid-to-pass-to-screencapture-l)


Note: I am not affiliated with these projects.</sub>